# Use applescript with safari to send content in mail

Tags: html, excel, email, safari, applescript

Sounds weird, but I have a mac word doc that I web preview in Safari and use Safari "share>email this page" to get the entire html content into the email. I have a script already that takes email addresses from excel one at a time and inserts it into the recipients and inserts the subject as well. I just can't figure out the applescript commands to send the active safari page into mac mail. Sorry if this is too complicated.

Your assistance is greatly respected

Cheers
Rob

```
set {firstName, eAddress} to getData()

repeat with i from 1 to count firstName
tell application "Mail"
    activate
    set mymail to make new outgoing message at the beginning of outgoing messages with properties {subject:"Your Complimentary Chocolate Recipe Book"}
    tell mymail
        make new to recipient at beginning of to recipients with properties {address:item i of eAddress}


    end tell
    --show message window (otherwise it's hidden)
    set visible of mymail to true
    --bring Mail to front
    activate
    send mymail
    set m to random number from 45 to 300
    delay m
end tell
end repeat


on getData()
set colA to {}
set colB to {}
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    tell active sheet
        set lastRow to first row index of (get end (last cell of column 1) direction toward the top)

        repeat with i from 3 to lastRow
            set end of colA to (value of range ("A" & i))
            set end of colB to (value of range ("B" & i))
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell

return {colA, colB}
end getData
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rob,

If you want to get the HTML source :

```
on get_page_data()
  tell application "Safari"
    return source of document of windows whose visible is true
  end tell
end
```

You could then set the content property of the outgoing message from your `make new` line in your code:

```
tell application "Mail"
    set mymail to make new outgoing message at the beginning of outgoing messages with properties {subject:"Your Complimentary Chocolate Recipe Book", content: get_page_data()}
-- etc
end tell
```